# No route matches [POST] "/users/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

Please help me for resolve this error.

Error:
No route matches [POST] "/users/new"

My code snippets are:

views/users/index.html.erb

```
<h1>This is Registration page..</h1>
<div class="sign">
<%= button_to "Registration",{:controller => "users", :action => "new",method: :get} %>
<%= button_to "Login",action:"login" , method: :get %>
</div>
```

config/route.rb

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      root "users#index"
      get "users/new" => "users#new"
      get "users/login" => "users#login"
      #get "users/new" => "users#new", as: new_user
      #get "users/login" => "users#login", as: login_user
   end
```

Please help me to setup the routes file.

Comment: change `<%= button_to "Registration",{:controller => "users", :action => "new",method: :get} %>` to `<%= button_to "Registration", new_user_path %>`

Comment: show your users controller

Comment: also I can suggest you for CRUD actions in routes use `resources :users`

Answer (score 2):

First make your life easier by naming your routes:

```
# in config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "users#index"
  get "users/new"   => "users#new",   :as => :new_user
  get "users/login" => "users#login", :as => :login
end
```

Furthermore notice that the `:method` argument is part of the third (not second) argument:

```
<%= button_to "Registration", new_user_path, :method => :get %>
<%= button_to "Login", login_path, :method => :get %>
```

Or without the named routes:

```
<%= button_to "Registration", { :controller => "users", :action => "new" }, :method => :get %>
<%= button_to "Login", { :action => "login" }, method => :get %>
```

Note the curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The default method type for `button_to` is `POST`. You have `posts_new_path` as type `GET`.

So better you use `link_to` instead of `button_to` and use css to convert these link to look like button.

```
<%= link_to "REGISTER",users_new_path%>
```

css should be like:

```
a:link, a:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 6em;  
  padding: 0.2em;
  line-height: 1.4;
  background-color: #94B8E9;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

a:hover {
 background-color: #369;
 color: #fff;
}
```