# Routing Error: No route matches [POST] "/flex_quiz/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, partials

In my rails app I'm trying to use a form partial to display the same quiz on the `new` and `edit` views.  I can see the new view page, but when I hit `<%= f.submit "Submit Answers" %>` I get an error saying `No route matches [POST] "/flex_quiz/new"`.

Here is the `form for` line in my partial:

```
<%= form_for @flex_quiz, url: url do |f| %>
```

And here's how the locals stand in my `new` view:

```
 <%= render partial: "quiz", locals: { url: new_flex_quiz_path, method: :post } %>
```

And my `edit` view:

```
<%= render "quiz", url: edit_flex_quiz_path(@flex_quiz), method: :put  %>
```

Here are the route paths:

```
         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
            ...     
flex_quiz_index GET    /flex_quiz(.:format)           flex_quiz#index
                POST   /flex_quiz(.:format)           flex_quiz#create
  new_flex_quiz GET    /flex_quiz/new(.:format)       flex_quiz#new
 edit_flex_quiz GET    /flex_quiz/:id/edit(.:format)  flex_quiz#edit
      flex_quiz GET    /flex_quiz/:id(.:format)       flex_quiz#show
                PATCH  /flex_quiz/:id(.:format)       flex_quiz#update
                PUT    /flex_quiz/:id(.:format)       flex_quiz#update
                DELETE /flex_quiz/:id(.:format)       flex_quiz#destroy
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix this?  I have looked at several similar posts (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519857/no-route-matches-post-users-new) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854976/no-route-matches-post-sessions-new-rails-4-in-action)) but since I'm using partials the solution here is going to have to be a bit different.

**EDIT**

Here are my definitions in my `flex_quiz_controller`:

```
class FlexQuizController < ApplicationController
before_action :require_sign_in

def show
  @flex_quiz = FlexQuiz.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @flex_quiz = current_user.build_flex_quiz
end

def create
  @flex_quiz = FlexQuiz.new

  @flex_quiz.flex01 = params[:flex_quiz][:flex01]
  @flex_quiz.flex02 = params[:flex_quiz][:flex02]
  @flex_quiz.flex03 = params[:flex_quiz][:flex03]
  @flex_quiz.flex04 = params[:flex_quiz][:flex04]
  @flex_quiz.flex05 = params[:flex_quiz][:flex05]
  @flex_quiz.flex06 = params[:flex_quiz][:flex06]
  @flex_quiz.flex07 = params[:flex_quiz][:flex07]
  @flex_quiz.flex08 = params[:flex_quiz][:flex08]
  @flex_quiz.flex09 = params[:flex_quiz][:flex09]
  @flex_quiz.flex10 = params[:flex_quiz][:flex10]

  @flex_quiz.user = current_user

  if @flex_quiz.save
    flash[:notice] = "Quiz results saved successfully."
    redirect_to user_path(current_user)
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Sorry, your quiz results failed to save."
    redirect_to welcome_index_path
  end
end

def edit
  @flex_quiz = FlexQuiz.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @flex_quiz = FlexQuiz.find(params[:id])

  @flex_quiz.assign_attributes(flex_quiz_params)

  if @flex_quiz.save
    flash[:notice] = "Post was updated successfully."
    redirect_to user_path(current_user)
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
    redirect_to welcome_index_path
  end
end

private
def flex_quiz_params
  params.require(:flex_quiz).permit(:flex01, :flex02, :flex03, :flex04, :flex05, :flex06, :flex07, :flex08, :flex09, :flex10)
end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to **create** new `flex_quiz` objects, then you're going to want to `POST` to `flex_quiz_index_path`.

Notice in your route paths, if you look at `new_flex_quiz`, the HTTP verb is a `GET`.

It may be slightly unintuitive, but the `new` action is actually a `GET` request.

The action in which the object is supposed to be created in is the `create` action.

So to solve your problem this should do the trick:

```
<%= render partial: "quiz", locals: { url: flex_quiz_index_path, method: :post } %>
```

**EDIT**:

1. Instead of defining locals, you can simply define your forms in `form_for` as such:

You will also have to define `@flex_quiz` in your controller actions as well (in your case `new` and `edit`) `form_for` will automatically infer the appropriate URL.

From [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for-label-Resource-oriented+style):

> However, further simplification is possible if the record passed to
>   form_for is a resource, i.e. it corresponds to a set of RESTful
>   routes, e.g. defined using the resources method in config/routes.rb.
>   In this case Rails will simply infer the appropriate URL from the
>   record itself.

2. **You'll also need to change the naming from singular form to plural.**

Comment: I tried it and I'm still getting an `No route matches [POST] "/flex_quiz/new"` error.

Comment: Try changing to `<%= form_for :flex_quiz, url: url, method: method do |f| %>`

Comment: @Liz Takehiro's answer is correct, but make sure you're declaring `url: flex_quiz_index_path, method: :post` in your `form_for`. It shouldn't be necessary to pass local variables in this case, since these helper methods are shared across your views.

Comment: Method has to be in the locals, because it's `method: :put` for the edit form.  And @Takehiro I tried `<%= form_for :flex_quiz, url: url, method: method do |f| %>` and still got the same error message.

Comment: Actually, `form_for` will take care of it for you, if you simply put `<%= form_for @flex_quiz do |f| %>`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for-label-Resource-oriented+style

Comment: I tried the simpler `form_for` you suggested, both with and without the locals  listed in the `new` view where the partial is rendered.  Same error both ways.

Comment: Oh wait, just noticed your controller names are singular. You want them to be plural instead. You can do this by running `rails d controller flex_quiz` `rails g controller flex_quizzes` and then copying and pasting everything you had in `FlexQuizController` and redefining the `routes`

Comment: I changed the controller name as you suggested and copied the contents of the old controller.  My routes don't seem to have changed...am I missing a step?

Comment: You're almost there I think, you need to define the routes your self. So in `routes.rb`, change to `resources :flex_quizzes`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110720/discussion-between-liz-and-takehiro-mouri).

Answer (score 0):

The rails to do resuable forms is:

app/views/flex_quiz/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@flex_quiz) do |f| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

app/views/flex_quiz/new.erb:

```
<h1>Create a new quiz</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

app/views/flex_quiz/edit.erb:

```
<h1>Edit a quiz</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

While using locals can often be a good idea its not needed here. Note we just pass the resource and not a URL to `form_for` - that is *convention over configuration* in action and is what makes Rails awesome.

Rails figures out all by itself what URL to use for the action attribute and what method to use based on if the resource has been saved.

However for this to work  you to actually follow the conventions. Make sure you are using the proper plural forms ([the plural of quiz is quizzes](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quiz)):

```
resources :flex_quizzes

class FlexQuizzesController < ApplicationController
end
```

Unfortunately when it comes to rest of your setup you need to revisit the drawing board. Its not very realistic to think that you can do this with a single model. You would usually have several models with relations:

```
class Quiz
  has_many :questions
end

class Question
  belongs_to :quiz
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer
  belongs_to :question
end

class UserQuiz
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :quiz
end

class UserAnswer
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer
end
```

You would use one or several controllers to let admins create the quizes and a separate controller to let users answer the quiz. Its a quite common domain so you should be able to find plenty of examples.